# similar file name ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've created a text input field which checks file names on my server. But if you want to do this you have to wirte the excactly filename. So I need a solution which displays me the file even though the input text isnt excactly the same.

HTML:

```
<form method="GET">
    <img src="search.png" height="28" alt="search" title="" />
    <input name="search-item" type="text" placeholder="Suchen..." autocomplete="off" />
</form>
<div id="search_suggest">
</div>
```

jQuery / ajax:

```
$('input[name=search-item]').on('change keyup paste', function() {
    if($('input[name=search-item]').val() === ""){
        $('#search_suggest').hide();
    }
    var input_movie = 'video/' + $('input[name=search-item]').val() + '.avi';
    var input_thumbnail = 'video/Thumbnail/' + $('input[name=search-item]').val() + '.png';
    $.ajax({
        url: input_movie,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function() {
            $('#search_suggest').show();
            $('#search_suggest').html('<a href="' + input_movie + '"><div class="searchedFile"><img src="' + input_thumbnail + '" height="35" /><span>DeadFighters</span></div></a>');
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#search_suggest').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

And by the way, of course any improvement on my script is welcomed.

Comment: Why are you showing client side code for a question which is about your server side code?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the Jquery UI [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

You will need a list of the filenames that are available, so maybe set up an ajax call to just do that first.

Then when the user is typing in the search field, it will show similar results matched against the list you built with the first Ajax call.

When a user selects a suggested result, you will have the exact file name to pass the file name directly to the ajax call you already have now.

It seems @Kaiido just answered a similar solution with a different library.

Comment: Yep, same solution, so it might be the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that rather than making a call to your server on every `change keyup paste`as @Quentin suggested, you should therefore make a first call to get the list of every files downloadable, store them in an array and use a closest string match library like [didyoumean.js](https://github.com/dcporter/didyoumean.js) by Dave Porter, which seems to do pretty well its job

```js
var list_files=['fuzzy','duzzy','file', 'names'];
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(){res.innerHTML=didYouMean(this.value, list_files)});
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dcporter/didyoumean.js/master/didYouMean-1.2.1.js"></script>
<div id="res"></div>
<input type="text">
```